# regex for address field in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Hello I need to validate addresses like the following

```
C/s-2, abc, pqr
C/s/2, abc, pqr
221B Baker Street
101, Baker Street, London, UK
221-B, Baker Street etc
```

basically looking for standard address types that I can validate using laravel's validation

I have tried following expressions

```
'address' => 'required|regex:/^(?=.*[0-9])[- ,\/0-9]+$/',
'address' => 'required|regex:/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/-]|[,\/]$/s',
'address' => 'required|regex:/(^([0-9]+ )?[a-zA-Z ]+$)/',
'address' => 'required|regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$)/',
```

but nothing has worked for me can you please help to get the right regex for such addresses

Thank you :)

Comment: There is no standard for the address format in the UK. If there were then it would need to cover addresses with neither number nor street (a family member has such an address) as well as more common forms. The only workable approach is to use postcode lookup with a person selecting the correct one amongst the many addresses for that postcode. Anything else will generate too many incorrect results.

Comment: ok then if assuming I'm having the address like I have mentioned what will be the regex for it? Actually I need to validate the address that I'm getting from Google Place API

Comment: Why would you want to validate the address format from a place lookup service? (Is this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/67392)?)

Comment: actually in UI the address field is editable so I need to check whether the field contains genuine address? and we can't make it readonly until clients agrees for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally got something that is working for me I don't know whether it will work for long or not but presently it is working well.

```
'address' => 'required|regex:/(^[-0-9A-Za-z.,\/ ]+$)/'
```

however the previous posted answer is also working well I don't know why he deleted that answer anyway I'm pasting his demo which worked for me

```
'address' => 'required|regex:/([- ,\/0-9a-zA-Z]+)/',
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/MyQmn2/1)**

Comment: I do it. Thanks and regards.